# R strucchange RSS and BIC for one breakpoint

Tags: r, breakpoints

The reference manual for the R strucchange package states:

> As the maximum of a sequence of F statistics is equivalent to the
>   minimum OLS estimator of the breakpoint in a 2-segment partition it
>   can be extracted by breakpoints from an object of class "Fstats" as
>   computed by Fstats.

Is the breakpoint extracted by the above approach always the same as the breakpoint extracted by applying coeftest to an object of class "breakpointsfull" when the "breaks" option is 1?  In other words, is the breakpoint extracted by calling breakpoints on an Fstats object (minimum RSS) always equal to the breakpoint extracted by calling coeftest on a breakpointsfull object (minimum BIC) when breaks = 1?

```
library(lmtest)
library(strucchange)

data("Nile")

fs.nile <- Fstats(Nile ~ 1)
breakpoints(fs.nile)

bp.nile <- breakpoints(Nile ~ 1)
coeftest(bp.nile, breaks = 1)
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more about the interpretation of statistical methods and not really a specific programming question. Perhaps it's better to ask this on [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I think it has both components: a conceptual side and a programming side. So I've answered the question here rather than suggesting to move it to Cross Validated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially yes. The breakpoint associated with the supF statistic (supWald or supLR) and the minimum RSS breakpoint in the linear regression model are identical.

Of course, the trimming/minimal segment size needs to be the same. The default is 15% in both `breakpoints()` (argument `h`) and `Fstats()` (arguments `from` and `to`). Also, no alternative covariance matrix estimator (`vcov`) must be used in `Fstats()`.

However, `breakpoints(Fstats(formula, ...))` just extracts a simple object of class `"breakpoints"` while `breakpoints(formula, ...)` sets up the whole `"breakpointsfull"` object from which confidence intervals, coefficient tests, information criteria etc. can be computed.