# Strucchange claims that there are no breakdates but still reports them

Tags: r, time-series

I'm not an expert at structural change analysis, so bear with me on this one. I have a set of quarterly data sets here (as a reproducible data set):

```
+------------+--------------+--+--+
|    date    | abandon_rate |  |  |
+------------+--------------+--+--+
| 2009-07-01 |       0.0833 |  |  |
| 2009-10-01 |       0.2500 |  |  |
| 2010-01-01 |       0.1000 |  |  |
| 2010-04-01 |       0.0833 |  |  |
| 2010-07-01 |       0.2857 |  |  |
| 2010-10-01 |       0.1667 |  |  |
| 2011-01-01 |       0.3333 |  |  |
| 2011-04-01 |       0.2727 |  |  |
| 2011-07-01 |       0.1250 |  |  |
| 2011-10-01 |       0.2143 |  |  |
| 2012-01-01 |       0.3000 |  |  |
| 2012-04-01 |       0.1538 |  |  |
| 2012-07-01 |       0.3333 |  |  |
| 2012-10-01 |       0.2500 |  |  |
| 2013-01-01 |       0.0909 |  |  |
| 2013-04-01 |       0.2000 |  |  |
| 2013-07-01 |       0.1111 |  |  |
| 2013-10-01 |       0.1905 |  |  |
| 2014-01-01 |       0.1579 |  |  |
| 2014-04-01 |       0.3043 |  |  |
| 2014-07-01 |       0.1429 |  |  |
| 2014-10-01 |       0.2609 |  |  |
| 2015-01-01 |       0.3518 |  |  |
| 2015-04-01 |       0.3182 |  |  |
| 2015-07-01 |       0.2381 |  |  |
| 2015-10-01 |       0.3810 |  |  |
| 2016-01-01 |       0.1111 |  |  |
| 2016-04-01 |       0.1200 |  |  |
| 2016-07-01 |       0.1250 |  |  |
| 2016-10-01 |       0.1538 |  |  |
| 2017-01-01 |       0.3000 |  |  |
+------------+--------------+--+--+
```

To my untrained eye, that looks OK to work with.

Likewise, when I go to obtain breakpoints, I get the following data:

```
Breakpoints at observation number:

m = 1   6               
m = 2           21 26   
m = 3   6       21 26   
m = 4   6    14 21 26   
m = 5   6    14 21 26 31
m = 6   6 11 16 21 26 31

Corresponding to breakdates:

m = 1   0.166666666666667                                                      
m = 2                                                   0.583333333333333
m = 3   0.166666666666667                                0.583333333333333
m = 4   0.166666666666667                   0.388888888888889 0.583333333333333
m = 5   0.166666666666667                   0.388888888888889 0.583333333333333
m = 6   0.166666666666667 0.305555555555556 0.444444444444444 0.583333333333333

m = 1                                      
m = 2   0.722222222222222                  
m = 3   0.722222222222222                  
m = 4   0.722222222222222                  
m = 5   0.722222222222222 0.861111111111111
m = 6   0.722222222222222 0.861111111111111

Fit:

m   0        1        2        3        4        5        6       
RSS   0.2769   0.2588   0.2287   0.2178   0.1958   0.1908   0.2010
BIC -65.8989 -61.1719 -58.4492 -53.0449 -49.7058 -43.4698 -34.4285
```

So to me it looks like there a few breakpoints. However, when I try to model these breakdates, I don't end up with the dates, but instead only end up with the values. Further, when I try to work around this with the following command I get this error:

```
> us1 <- lm(US_abandonment_rates_ts ~ breakfactor(bp.US_abandonment,   breaks = 1))
Error in model.frame.default(formula = US_abandonment_rates_ts ~ breakfactor(bp.US_abandonment,  : 
variable lengths differ (found for 'breakfactor(bp.US_abandonment, breaks = 1)')
```

Any suggestions as to what I might be doing wrong? Thanks!

EDIT: I have followed Achim Zeilis's advice here ([R strucchange RSS and BIC for one breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30562109/r-strucchange-rss-and-bic-for-one-breakpoint?rq=1)) and have run a Chow test on my data to identify a single structural break:

```
fs.US_abandon <- Fstats(US_abandonment_rates_ts ~ 1)
> breakpoints(fs.abandon)

    Optimal 2-segment partition: 

Call:
breakpoints.Fstats(obj = fs.US_abandon)

Breakpoints at observation number:
6 

Corresponding to breakdates:
0.1388889
```

So clearly there is a breakpoint at point 6 in my dataset (2011-01-01). How then would I be able to examine the remaining break points? Thank you.

EDIT: Graph breaking down my data:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think it´s hard to import your data in R so just a few words:

What does the graphic look like? Are there clear indications of a structural break?

**Estimating Breakpoints is complicated. The most tests have problems to find end-of-sample breaks because they are splitting the data in 2 subsamples and are estimating a simple model. But this model needs relative large amount of observations to be valid. (can be modifided by h=XX in `breakpoints`)**

**Even when 2011-01-01 is an breakpoint it is, in my opinion, impossible to model this because you have only 6 oberservations before the break.**

[Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/309420/structural-change) you can see my approach to find structural breaks which is supported by Mr. Zeileis.

In short:

1. run supF Test
2. if break = `breakpoints`
3. split the sample
4. repeat with each new sample until the supF test finds no indication of further breaks

Comment: Hey Martin, have just added my data into the description. Thanks!

Comment: Eyeballing at this I wouldn't think you'd have to worry about structural breaks.  Besides the fact that you couldn't model them anyway. ;)